# Visual Studio: how to ignore known exceptions when debugging?

Tags: django, visual-studio

I'm debugging with Visual Studio Code Version 1.34.

I've setup a breakpoint that is not reached because of exceptions that are not critical.

How do I stop that behaviur? I'm coping the configuration file for debugging with Django in VSC.

**launch.json**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Extension",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "npm"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload",
                "--nothreading"
            ],
            "django": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In python you can use a *try* and *except*

If you know the exception that is being thrown:

```
try:
    with open('file.txt') as file:
        read_data = file.read()
except FileNotFoundError as fnf_error:
    print(fnf_error)

print('this will still be executed')
```

If you don't know what type of exception is thrown:

```
try:
    function_that_throws()
except:
    print('caught exception')

print('this is still executed')
```